# Dataframe editing by filtering column names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have two dataframes

I will use [this dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gx3qE.png) to filter [that dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gIGts.png) by the column names.

How can i do that with pandas?

Comment: Please do not post pics and please post [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Refrain from showing your dataframe as an image.  Your question needs a minimal reproducible example consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output, and only the relevant code necessary to reproduce the problem. See [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) for best practices related to Pandas questions.

Answer (score -1):

If the data frame with the column names all exist(No non-existent value) then you can just turn the column names into a list and put it in like this

```
df = df[column_list]
```

Otherwise like this

```
df.loc[:, df.columns.isin(column_list)`
```